# Working with Realm and result JSON

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, realm

I am new to realm and I am trying to use Realm in my project. Here I am trying to parse JSON and save it using realm. When I am trying to loop through the result array error occurs

> 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginwritetransaction on an RLMRealm instance first'

This is the JSON result:

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"parent_id":0,"name":"JenniferMaenle","title":"Ms","phone":"","address":"Toled, ohio","email":"jlmaenle@aol.com","image":"44381525_2017.jpg","relation_id":5,"created_at":null,"updated_at":"2017-08-10 02:30:05"},{"id":2, "parent_id":1,"name":"Khadeeja","title":"","phone":"","address":"","email":"","image":"Khadeeja_2017-07-17.jpg","relation_id":2,"created_at":null,"updated_at":"2017-07-17 08:3:12"}]}
```

I am trying to parse JSON and save it in the Realm database. Here is my try:

```
class Person: Object {

dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var title = ""
dynamic var address = ""

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.add()

}

func add(){

   guard let data = dataFromFile("ServerData") else { return }

    let persons = Person()

    do {

        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: AnyObject] {

            if let data = json["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]{

                for eachItem in data{
                    persons.name = eachItem["name"] as! String
                    persons.title = eachItem["title"] as! String
                    persons.address = eachItem["address"] as! String

                    try! realm.write {
                        realm.add(persons)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    } catch {

        print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not modify the `persons` object and add it to the realm again. The error you see is because you add persons to the realm and then edit it on the second iteration in the `for eachItem in data` again. `Persons` is already added to the realm in this iteration and you try to give it a new name outside a realm write transaction. That's why you see the error. It's better to create a new object for every person.

```
func add(){
    guard let data = dataFromFile("ServerData") else { return }

    do {
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let data = json["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]{
                for eachItem in data{
                    let persons = Person()
                    persons.name = eachItem["name"] as! String
                    persons.title = eachItem["title"] as! String
                    persons.address = eachItem["address"] as! String

                    try! realm.write {
                        realm.add(persons)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Yannick Working perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates, you need to preform the transaction inside a write,

One option is to write each person individually:

```
for eachItem in data{
    let person = Person()
    person.name = eachItem["name"] as! String
    person.title = eachItem["title"] as! String
    person.address = eachItem["address"] as! String

    try! realm.write {
         realm.add(person)
    }
}
```

Second option is to build an object and then write:

```
for eachItem in data{
    let person = Person();
    person.name = eachItem["name"] as! String
    person.title = eachItem["title"] as! String
    person.address = eachItem["address"] as! String
    persons.add(person)
}
try! realm.write {
    realm. append(persons)
}
```

You might need to make few changes to this, but this is the idea.